# Mongodb is returning wierdly formatted data

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

When i try to get this data from my mongodb database using `flask-restful`and `pymongo` i get some wierdly formatted data.

For example.

This is what the data looks like in the database.

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5217f3cc7466c06862c4a4f7"), "Hello" : "World" }`

This is what it looks like when it gets returned from the database.

`"{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5217f3cc7466c06862c4a4f7\"}, \"Hello\": \"World\"}"`

Using this code:

```
def toJSON(data):
    return json.dumps(data, default=json_util.default)
```

And this:

```
def get(self, objectid):
    collection = db["products"]
    result = collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(objectid)})
    return toJSON(result)
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask-restful` expects you to return a `dictionary` and not `json` here. It would convert the dictionary into `json` on its own. So your code should look like

```
def get(self, objectid):
    collection = db["products"]
    result = collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(objectid)})
    result['_id'] = result['_id'].__str__()
    return result
```

When you return `json` `flask-restful` sees that and infers that it is a string and escapes the double quotes.

Comment: This is what i get if i return result: TypeError: ObjectId('5217f3cc7466c06862c4a4f7') is not JSON serializable

Comment: @Razcou I changed the code to avoid this error. So you have to write some kind of wrapper on your mongo interacton code to convert `ObjectId` to `str` and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

No, that's supposed to be like that.

MongoDB uses BSON, which extends JSON with some extra types, such as ObjectId. To represent those in JSON, you get the weird-looking `$oid` and friends.

The backslashes are most likely added by some tool to allow for quotes inside of a String literal (which is enclosed by quotes). Unless you are somehow double-encoding things.

Comment: But what about all those backslashes? Where do they come from?

Comment: I added some more code in the question. That is all i do to return the data.

Comment: I discovered that it is flask-restful that adds the backspaces somehow. Gotta figure out why.